# Related tags algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm, tags, cassandra

I need to find a way to fetch related videos by mainly looking for related tags.

First let's take a look the way my tags are stored in the database:

[image]

Please note that this is not MySQL database, I'm using [**Cassandra**](http://cassandra.apache.org/).

So as you can see each tag contains a list of post ids that have that tag. This way fetching post ids would be easy, in SQL language I would say:

`SELECT * from tags WHERE id  = "cars" AND id = "movies"`.

Well this part is easy now i have tons of posts with related tags, right?

But here comes the problem which i can't overcome. Since one post can have more related tags than the other it would be a lot more important than other posts. Of course i could hack something together to see which post has more related tags, but here comes the other  a lot more serious problem.

Say we have 20 tags, so we look for 20 rows, and those 20 rows together contains around 100 million ids, running trough 100 million ids and comparing them to each other would require way to many resources and time. So I'm asking how this situation can be improved?

Comment: @phpNoOb Your nick name answers your question

Comment: I think something like `SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM tags WHERE post_ids LIKE '%id here%';` would help.

Comment: You should rethink the way of storing many-to-many relations.

Comment: @madfriend Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: I think your data is structured/optimised for NoSql databases. With Cassandra, a NoSql dbms, you don't have to worry about performance. I'm not familiar with Cassandra, but in MongoDB, $elemMatch queries in array property runs pretty fast.

Comment: @SmitPatel Well with my current approach most of the load is pushed to the server, but know that you've mentioned it, i could try to put more work on the database.

Answer (score 0):

Like most people are saying in the comments..

You may want to consider changing the way you manage tags in your database. I assume that you have a 'posts' table; perhaps you should add a 'tags' column to that table instead having a separate table for tags.

In addition to having very fast access to associated tags..

If space isn't really an issue, you could do a fulltext index (or rather, the Cassandra equivalent) of each post's 'tags' column, and be able to even access related posts in a short amount of time. Of course, you will still have to put limits on your search for related posts, but that's just a matter of using LIMIT.